# GWT 2.6.1 Using SuperDevMode with -bindAddress

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm having issues trying to debug my application when using :

```
-bindAddress
```

Without specifying a bind address I am able to use SuperDevMode to debug my application however I get the following error when specifying an IP to bind to.

```
14:36:54,998 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyApp]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-7) MyControlServiceServlet: Can't open serialization policy URL: http://localhost:9876/policies/13C789BD0DD217A7A3FE375FECFD0366.gwt.rpc: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Just interested to know if I need to specify anything else in my SuperDevMode config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring your server such that your servlets load the serialization policies from the CodeServer, you need to use the bindAddress. If you launch the CodeServer such that it binds to a specific IP, it no longer binds to localhost which produces the error you're seeing. So either bind to 0.0.0.0 or adjust your configuration accordingly.